# What's the filterCriteria in the Type.FindMembers C#

Tags: c#, reflection, filter, memberinfo

I've been searching he internet for hours without finding a satisfying answer for this 
I know it's what determines what would be included in the MemberInfo object but what exactly are the possible values to this

```
 public class TestTypeOf
{
    private int tt;
    private string tt2;

    public void test()
    {

        Type type = typeof(TestTypeOf);
        MemberInfo[] info = type.FindMembers(MemberTypes.All, BindingFlags.NonPublic, new MemberFilter(searchFilter), "tt");
        Console.WriteLine(type.BaseType);
        Console.WriteLine(type.Assembly);
        Console.WriteLine(type.Attributes);
        Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);

        foreach (var Info in info)
            Console.WriteLine(Info.ToString());
    }

    private static bool searchFilter(MemberInfo memObj, object obj)
    {
        if (memObj.Name.ToString() == obj.ToString())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

that's the code I have been using and it returns and empty array I know that the search criteria has a wrong parameter but is there's something else??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `BindingFlags.Instance` as well, `NonPublic` is not enough:

```
MemberInfo[] info = type.FindMembers(MemberTypes.All, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, new MemberFilter(searchFilter), "tt");
```

Your other parameters are fine.

Comment: Interesting. This helped me too. But why is BindingFlags.Instance required as well. I was using BindingFlags.Default originally and was finding nothing. After changing to Instance and Public I started finding stuff.